# Trying to ID a printed character that looks like a script M

Tags: words

I am reading a movie scenario magazine and came across this character:

[image]

Here is an example with some context:

[image]

I can't tell if it is a Japanese character or a typographical mark or something else. What could it be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

「〽」　is called 「庵点{いおりてん}」.

It is a typographic mark that has traditionally been used to indicate that what follows it is (a part of) a poem, song, etc.

It is also said to be the origin of the modern Japanese quotation marks 「」.

「庵{いおり}」, by itself, means a "little hut with a thatched roof" in case someone thought 「〽」 indeed looked like a roof.

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BA%B5%E7%82%B9

There is no English page for this Wiki article.

Comment: The English Wikipedia collects this mark in the [Japanese typographic symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_typographic_symbols#Other_special_marks) article. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/〽) also has a (rather short) explanation in English.